# Download pem file using Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell, x509certificate

I am attempting to download a cert pem file from a website using Invoke-WebRequest with the command below and then save it locally on my machine:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "Full_URL_to_pem_file" OutFile "C:\Temp\certFile.pem"
```

I can successfully do this but it does not get saved as the correct file type because when I attempt to import it using the commands below, it throws Crypto Exception error:

```
$rootCert = "C:\Temp\certFile.pem"
$root = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$root.Import($rootCert)
```

Comment: Aten't you forgetting the dash in front of parameter `OutFile` ?

Comment: not a dash, but pipe operator.

Comment: I mean, the right command is `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "Full_URL_to_pem_file" | OutFile "C:\Temp\certFile.pem"`

Comment: @Crypt32 No, this is about the **parameter** `-OutFile`, not the cmdlet `Out-File`. All named parameters in PowerShell must be preceeded by a dash. P.S. I just stumbled upon your comments. Please if you want to notify someone in a comment use the `@` sign, followed by the erson's name.